# Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

**I am facing this issue when I'm running my react-native project**.

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1005 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
WARNING:: Please remove usages of `jcenter()` Maven repository from your build scripts and migrate your build to other Maven repositories.
This repository is deprecated and it will be shut down in the future.
See http://developer.android.com/r/tools/jcenter-end-of-service for more information.
Currently detected usages in: root project 'SearchWork', project ':app', project ':react-native-community_masked-view', ...

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
> 39 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 37 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @5eb31167

- Try:
  Run with --stack trace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @5eb31167

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\malik.usman\Desktop\Office Documents\SearchWork\SearchWork\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\malik.usman\Desktop\Office Documents\SearchWork\SearchWork\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\malik.usman\Desktop\Office Documents\SearchWork\SearchWork\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\malik.usman\Desktop\Office Documents\SearchWork\SearchWork\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

This is project configuration:

```
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 29
targetSdkVersion = 29
ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
```

Gradle Version:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip`

Comment: Please improve your title. Your title should be clear enough to define your problem

Comment: @MuhammadZahabAhmadKhan is it enough now??

Answer (score 0):

try to open in android studio, build again and you will see error to solve.